# Updating a span using jQuery, based on a simple live calculation from a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, live

So I have a tiny issue with some jQuery that I would appriciate some help on. I have two values, the one I get from an input field, the other from a static element. So it should be fairly simple, and I would like it as "LIVE" as possible. I made a JSFIDDLE for the sake of it. Please check it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/pzSxL/2/

```
$('#bet-amount').keyup(function() {
var amount = $("#bet-amount").val();
var odds = 2;

var total = amount * odds;

$("#potential-payout").val(total); 
});
```

Any help is greatly appriciated, and I hope that you can see that what i want is to update the span containing a 0 as default.

Best regards,
André!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made mistake with `span.val();` You should use html or text jQuery method to update html inside span, and another thing, you should parse value from input field. So this is your function.

```
$('#bet-amount').keyup(function() {
    var amount = parseFloat($("#bet-amount").val());
    var odds = 2;

    var total = amount * odds;

    $("#potential-payout").html(total); // sets the total price input to the quantity * price
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: http://jsfiddle.net/pzSxL/3/

```
 var total = amount * odds;

 $("#potential-payout").text(total);
       //  ------------^^^^^-----------you had to change this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the val function to change inner html. Html is the correct function:

```
$("#potential-payout").html(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bet-amount').on('keyup', function() {
    var amount = parseFloat( this.value ),
        odds   = 2,
        total  = amount * odds;

    $("#potential-payout").text(total);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzSxL/8/)

The returned result from value is always a string, so a little parsing should be done, and when setting the "value" of the span, that is actually not the value, but the text content, and `text()` would be more appropriate.